# sudo apt-get update does not work?

Tags: 12.04, installation, updates

I'm running newly installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my computer.

After the command`sudo apt-get update`, my terminal shows the following message:

`Reading package lists... Done`

After that, nothing happens. What's wrong?

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead? Dropping back to your shell after updating the package lists seems like the normal behaviour to me.

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing wrong with your system: `sudo apt-get update` will only update the package list.
To really update packages, you have to type: `sudo apt-get upgrade` afterwards as well!

**edit:**

let me add to this that `sudo apt-get upgrade` will finish with `Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded` if you already have installed all latest updates. When you already have installed all updates for your system, `sudo apt-get upgrade` will **not** reinstall stuff. If you get a message along the lines of `x packages have been kept back`, you should run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: sorry sir but here no any downloaded packages are installed.

Comment: You can disagree with the answer, but it is factually accurate.  Run `sudo apt-get update` and then also `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  Think of it as the difference between 'checking for available updates' and then 'upgrading the available updates,' in a sense.  He is correct.

Comment: If you system is up to date already, nothing will be downloaded or updated with `sudo apt-get update`. Sometimes packages are held and you need to do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, see the apt-get man page for details. If you are having a problem , post the error message or output, but I see nothing wrong or abnormal here.

Comment: Such confusion would not happen if the apt commands were "check-updates" and "update" instead of "update" and "upgrade".

Answer (score 1):

This might be because your

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

is empty.

If so, [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch) helps you get a default sources.list.

This Generator right now supports version later than 12.04.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of only updating, you can as well do it by using update manager.

Press the Superkey (Windows key) to launch the Dash and search for Update Manager
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade